# Efficiently writing this formula in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, rdbms

Say I have table and these are its sample rows

```
ChangeID    Change
   1         102
   2         105
   3         107
   4         110
```

The change formula is

```
(CurrentRowChange - PreviousRowChange) / PreviousRowChange
```

Hence:

- for 1st row it should be `0`
- for 2nd row it should be `(105 - 102) / 102`

and so on. How can I efficiently write this formula in SQL?

I know I can write a scalar function and then do a RowNumber and order By ChangeID and fetch the row number's Change value and then find the current row number - 1 and then fetch that row's Change value and do a divide.

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Can i use `ChangeID` as natural number sequence?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Sure. Go ahead. No need to do RowNumber.

Comment: Your expression can be simplified to `(CurrentRowChange / PreviousRowChange) -1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give this a try, assuming that `CHANGEID` can be deleted and it is `IDENTITY`.

```
WITH changeList
AS
(
    SELECT ChangeID, [Change],
           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ChangeID ASC)) -1 AS rn
    FROM   TableName
),
normalList
AS
(
    SELECT ChangeID, [Change],
           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ChangeID ASC)) AS rn
    FROM   TableName
)
SELECT a.ChangeID, a.[Change], 
       COALESCE((a.Change - b.change) / (b.change * 1.0),0) result
FROM   changeList a
       LEFT JOIN normalList b
          ON a.rn = b.rn
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78f6e/13)

Comment: Yes and I like this solution more even though Andomar is cleaner because this solution handles cases when the ChangeID might not be sequential and *PreviousRowChange* might not be same as CurrentChangeID - 1.

Comment: +1 But I would add an `... / NULLIF(b.change,0)` to prevent `division by zero` error.

Comment: @Jack: Andomar's solution shows that you could do with just one ROW_NUMBER() call. You would use the ranking value in the join condition the way Andomar's solution is using ChangeId.

Comment: @AndriyM I also agree with Andomar's answer if the `ChangeID` is in sequence otherwise the value will be zero, example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1c43/1

Answer (score 4):

```
select  cur.*
,       case
        when prev.ChangeId is null then 0
        else 1.0 * (cur.Change - prev.Change) / prev.Change
        end
from    Table1 cur
left join
        Table1 prev
on      cur.ChangeId = prev.ChangeId + 1
```

[SQL Fiddle example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59faa/8/0)

Comment: Superb and simple :). Excellent. Just needs a bit tweaking. Results aren't correct.

Comment: Should be (cur.Change - prev.Change) / Cast(prev.Change as float)

Comment: Right, added `1.0 * ` which should have the same result.

Comment: @DanBracuk: True, but the comment to the question says that ChangeID is a "natural number sequence", so that seemed a valid assumption

Comment: Not if a row gets deleted.

Comment: @DanBracuk: You are right. However, the OP was explicit in [his comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672316/efficiently-writing-this-formula-in-sql-server-2008/14672410#comment20509200_14672316).

Answer (score 0):

While the ChangeID's are sequential in the sample, I wouldn't assume that they always are.  So I would do something like this:

```
 with RankedIDs as
 select ChangeID
 , Change
 , rank() over
 (partition by ChangeID order by ChangeId) rank
 where something maybe ;

 select case
 when r1.rank = 1 then 0
 else (r1.change - r2.change) / r2.change
 end SomeName
 from RankedIds r1 join RankedIds r2 on r1.rank = r2.rank + 1
```

That's the basic idea.  You might want to add divide by zero protection

Answer (score 0):

```
select T1.ChangeID,
       (1.0 * T1.Change / T2.Change) - 1 as Result
from TableName as T1
  outer apply (
              select top(1) T.Change
              from TableName as T
              where T.ChangeID < T1.ChangeID
              order by T.ChangeID desc
              ) as T2
```